# Swiss Ephemeris program swetest - different output in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu-18.04

I have been using the SWETEST program that comes bundled with the Swiss Ephemeris software to calculate the positions of various planets in terms of longitudes. So far, I have been using Windows10 and I have been getting values comparable with popular commercial software.

Recently, I have tried to move my application to Ubuntu ( specifically, the Ubuntu VM that comes with Google Colab ) and the first challenge was that, unlike Windows, there is no Linux executable available at the site. They provide the C code and a Makefile to compile the same.

I used the gcc available on Colab gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0 and the Make file to compile the file. There were some warnings but the program compiled and executes as expected.

The problem is that the longitude values generated in the Windows version is different from that generated in the Ubuntu version. The difference is not large, but still significant. Especially for the Ascendant.

The actual compilation can be seen at [this URL](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lCpnv-CXthBEkgxr8BJje9LLoST5UJjb)

Is there a way to resolve this problem and if so, where do I start?

the Output of the make command is given below

```
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swetest.c     
swetest.c: In function ‘main’:
swetest.c:1377:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  printf(stimeout);
         ^~~~~~~~
swetest.c:1712:4: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
    if (hpos_meth == 1)
    ^~
swetest.c:1714:6: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
      if (ipl == SE_FIXSTAR)
      ^~
swetest.c:1833:12: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
     printf(smod);
            ^~~~
swetest.c: In function ‘print_line’:
swetest.c:2017:32: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
         if (is_label) { printf(slon); break; }
                                ^~~~
swetest.c:2026:32: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
         if (is_label) { printf(slon); break; }
                                ^~~~
swetest.c:2046:32: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
         if (is_label) { printf(slon); break; }
                                ^~~~
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swedate.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swehouse.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swejpl.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swemmoon.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swemplan.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swepcalc.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         sweph.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swepdate.c     
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swephlib.c     
swephlib.c: In function ‘swe_get_astro_models’:
swephlib.c:4271:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_PREC_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4271:44: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_PREC_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
                                            ^~~~~
swephlib.c:4273:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_PREC_DEFAULT_SHORT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4273:50: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_PREC_DEFAULT_SHORT) imod = 0; break;
                                                  ^~~~~
swephlib.c:4275:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_NUT_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4275:43: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_NUT_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
                                           ^~~~~
swephlib.c:4277:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_SIDT_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4277:44: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_SIDT_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
                                            ^~~~~
swephlib.c:4279:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_BIAS_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4279:44: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_BIAS_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
                                            ^~~~~
swephlib.c:4281:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_JPLHOR_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4281:46: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_JPLHOR_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
                                              ^~~~~
swephlib.c:4283:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_JPLHORA_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4283:47: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_JPLHORA_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
                                               ^~~~~
swephlib.c:4285:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (imod == SEMOD_DELTAT_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
  ^~
swephlib.c:4285:46: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  if (imod == SEMOD_DELTAT_DEFAULT) imod = 0; break;
                                              ^~~~~
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swecl.c     
swecl.c: In function ‘swe_rise_trans_true_hor’:
swecl.c:4444:11: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
           if (!do_fixstar)
           ^~
swecl.c:4447:6: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
      if (rsmi & SE_BIT_GEOCTR_NO_ECL_LAT)
      ^~
cc   -c -g -Wall -fPIC         swehel.c     
swehel.c: In function ‘calc_rise_and_set’:
swehel.c:478:1: warning: this ‘else’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
 else
 ^~~~
swehel.c:484:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘else’
   iflag = epheflag|SEFLG_SPEED|SEFLG_EQUATORIAL;
   ^~~~~
ar r libswe.a   swedate.o swehouse.o swejpl.o swemmoon.o swemplan.o swepcalc.o sweph.o swepdate.o swephlib.o swecl.o swehel.o
ar: creating libswe.a
cc   -g -Wall -fPIC        -o swetest swetest.o -L. -lswe -lm -ldl
```

Answer (score 0):

The motivation behind this exercise -- of recompiling the program in Ubuntu -- was motivated by the need, or desire, to migrate from the Windows to the Unix/Ubuntu platform, in particular on a hosted VM environment like Google Colab. The same objective has now been achieved through a completely different route. 
There exists a Python package called [pyswisseph](https://pypi.org/project/pyswisseph/) that if installed gives you the direct ability to call the necessary and relevant functions to get identical results. 
 
A sample Colab notebook that demonstrates how this can be done is [shared here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HaPAIYGj0cYGYnhJ227I3vwZYuQ8V_OG).